# Interpreting Root Objects

Tags: equation-solving

I have solved this system of equations in *Mathematica* for $x$ where the coefficients of the equations were functions of $a,b$ and $c$. *Mathematica* then displays real solutions $x$ with constraints on $a,\,b$ and $c$.

The constraints for $c$ are written in function of roots objects $\mbox{Root}[f(z),k]$, where $f(z)$ is a quartic polynomial in $z$. In the output, I see for instance $\mbox{Root}[f(z),1] < c \leq \mbox{Root}[f(z),2]$. On the other hand, I also see the condition $0<c<\mbox{Root}[f(z),3]$.

I suppose I can thus assume that $f(z)$ has certainly three real roots (since $f(z)$ is a quartic with real coefficients it should have four reals)? Secondly, I assume that $\mbox{Root}[f(z),1] < \mbox{Root}[f(z),2]$? However, can I also assume that $\mbox{Root}[f(z),2] < \mbox{Root}[f(z),3]$?

The *Mathematica* code for the system is:

```
Reduce[
     16 x^4 - 40 a x^3 + (15 a^2 + 24 b) x^2 - 18 a b x + 3 b^2 == 0 
  && 5 a x - 4 x^2 - b > 0 
  && 15 a x - 20 x^2 - 3 b < 0 
  && 4 x^3 - 8 c x^2 + 5 c a x - c b > 0 
  && c > 0 && x > 0, 
     x, Reals]
```

Comment: Why not to give us "this system of equations", so that we see precisely what are you writing about?

Comment: This is the Mathematica code for the system:

Reduce[16 x^4 - 40 a x^3 + (15 a^2 + 24 b) x^2 - 18 a b x + 3 b^2 == 0 && 5 a x - 4 x^2 - b > 0 && 15 a x - 20 x^2 - 3 b < 0 && 4 x^3 - 8 c x^2 + 5 c a x - c b > 0 && c > 0 && x > 0, x,Reals]

Comment: It is better now, but it is not clear yet, what do you want to achieve. Your equation without the inequalities is solvable directly, though the solution is huge. It seems that, generally, this system should give a domain(s) in the (a,b,c) space. Is the defining of this domain - your aim? If not, what?

Comment: to answer part of the question, the `Root` expressions are indexed in order reals first in ascending order followed by complex, with the caveat that if you apply `ToRadicals` to a root expression containing parameters that ordering is not guaranteed.   I don't think `c<Root[,1]` can be interpreted as a guarantee there is a real root, more *if there is a real root* `c` is less than the smallest root.

Comment: @george2079: concerning $c<\mbox{Root}[,1]$, what other possible interpretation is there? I mean, given that $c<0$, it can't be a complex number so I don't think there is any other option that c<Root[,1] means Root[,1] is real, though I can't really prove it.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: yes, the aim is to find the $(a,b,c)$ space such that the system admits a real solution. Given that $c<0$, how can I interpret the roots $\mbox{Root}[,1],\mbox{Root}[,2]$ and $\mbox{Root}[,3]$? If I can't interpret these roots properly then I can't set up the $(a,b,c)$ domain.

Comment: Root is actually - the exact solution, Mathematica returns you. Sometimes it can be expressed in terms of analytical functions using the `ToRadicals` function of Mathematica. In other cases `ToRadicals`  has no effect, but you still can operate `Root` the same way you do with any analytical function: you can plot it, or obtain its numeric values (of course, if a, b and c are fixed) by applying the function `N` to it. You may generally regard it as a sort of a special function.  See the next comment.

Comment: You do not know, what is inside, but you may address it and get the result.  But your problem itself seems to be solvable much easier. Look, making this: `el1 = Eliminate[{16 x^4 - 40 a x^3 + (15 a^2 + 24 b) x^2 - 18 a b x +3 b^2 == 0, 5 a x - 4 x^2 - b == 0}, x]; Solve[el1, a]` you get `{{a -> -Sqrt[b]}, {a -> Sqrt[b]}} `. Here I took the equation and the first inequality, which I wrote as the equation. This gives you the boundaries of the domain you are after. The other boundaries you get combining the equation with the other inequalities also transformed into the equations.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not exactly what I need. I knew that most people do not prefer root objects. However, since I know the values of $(a,b,c)$ in my numerical calculations, these root objects do not form a problem since I can easily compute the roots numerically. The only question was if there was a possibility to interpret $\mbox{Root}[,3]$? It is unfortunate that these root objects seem like a mystery.

Comment: This`Reduce[16 x^4 - 40 a x^3 + (15 a^2 + 24 b) x^2 - 18 a b x + 3 b^2 == 
   0 && 5 a x - 4 x^2 - b == 0 && 15 a x - 20 x^2 - 3 b < 0 && 
  4 x^3 - 8 c x^2 + 5 c a x - c b > 0 && c > 0 && x > 0, x, Reals]` is different to that `Reduce[16 x^4 - 40 a x^3 + (15 a^2 + 24 b) x^2 - 18 a b x + 3 b^2 == 
   0 && 5 a x - 4 x^2 - b == 0 && 15 a x - 20 x^2 - 3 b < 0 && 
  4 x^3 - 8 c x^2 + 5 c a x - c b > 0 && c > 0 && x > 0, {x, a, b, 
  c}, Reals]`. Both are valid only if the second inequality is made an equality. So the question is underdetermined.